# ScrollView and little horizontal bar under menu items?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal bar view under my menu items and whenever I tap one of the menu items it appears under that item. I have named it `movingView` inside my code. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Here is a screenshot]

And under that menu I have a `UIScrollView`. I have placed 5 views inside that `UIScrollView` and I am able to swipe between them. Now whenever I swipe, I want that horizontal bar view under my menu item follow my selection. For example when I tap pistol, it moves from rifle to pistol. I want that to happen when I swipe from first page to second inside the `UIScrollView`.

Please someone help me. It's been 3 days and I couldn't figure out how to do this.

MY CODE:

```
class TabViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIImageView!

    var movingView = UIView()

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    var rifleViewController: UIViewController!
    var pistolViewController: UIViewController!
    var shotgunViewController: UIViewController!
    var smgsViewController: UIViewController!
    var sniperViewController: UIViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        rifleViewController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rifles")
        sniperViewController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "snipers")
        smgsViewController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "smgss")
        shotgunViewController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "shotguns")
        pistolViewController = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pistols")

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 5, height: self.view.frame.height)

        rifleViewController.view.frame = scrollView.bounds
        scrollView.addSubview(rifleViewController.view)

        pistolViewController.view.frame = scrollView.bounds
        pistolViewController.view.frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width
        scrollView.addSubview(pistolViewController.view)

        shotgunViewController.view.frame = scrollView.bounds
        shotgunViewController.view.frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * 2
        scrollView.addSubview(shotgunViewController.view)

        smgsViewController.view.frame = scrollView.bounds
        smgsViewController.view.frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * 3
        scrollView.addSubview(smgsViewController.view)

        sniperViewController.view.frame = scrollView.bounds
        sniperViewController.view.frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * 4
        scrollView.addSubview(sniperViewController.view)


        movingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: backgroundView.frame.maxY - 5, width: screenWidth / 5, height: 10))
        movingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        backgroundView.addSubview(movingView)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func riflePressTab(_ sender: Any)
    {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) , animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func pistolPressTab(_ sender: Any)
    {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width, y: 0) , animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func shotgunPressTab(_ sender: Any)
    {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, y: 0) , animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func smgsPressTab(_ sender: Any)
    {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, y: 0) , animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func sniperPressTab(_ sender: Any)
    {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width * 4, y: 0) , animated: true)
    }


    @IBAction func didPressTab(_ sender: UIButton)
        {

        let newx = sender.frame.origin.x

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2)
            {
            self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newx
            }
        }
}
```

I have tried this but when i run my app, nothing happens when i scroll

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    //Assuming your views are of full screen width or just change the SCREEN_WIDTH to whatever width your views occupy
    //This will give you which index you are on, i.e you are showing the first view or second or third
    let newIndex = scrollView.contentOffset.x/UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width;

    animateUnderBar(forIndex index:Int(newIndex))
}

func animateUnderBar(forIndex index:Int){

    let newx = self.movingView.frame.origin.x + CGFloat(index) * self.movingView.bounds.size.width

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2)
    {
        self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your class conform to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and implement the following method-

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    //Assuming your views are of full screen width or just change the SCREEN_WIDTH to whatever width your views occupy
    //This will give you which index you are on, i.e you are showing the first view or second or third
    let newIndex = scrollView.contentOffset.x/UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width; 

    animateUnderBar(forIndex :Int(newIndex))
}

func animateUnderBar(forIndex index:Int){

    let newx = view.frame.origin.x + CGFloat(index) * view.bounds.size.width

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2)
        {
        self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newx
        }
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**

You should use a `UICollectionView` instead of a `UIScrollView` as it will automatically handle displaying of views inside of cells without you having to manually set `contentOffSet`. Moving under bar will also be easier as it will simply be a matter of using the `indexPath.item` property to move the under bar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting this error: 'Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operants of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat' ' in this line :         let newx = self.movingView.frame.origin.x + index * self.movingView.bounds.size.width

Comment: Ahh overlooked that, just do `CGFloat(index)`

Comment: I have edited my question. I convert CGFloats to Int and now i got no error. But when i scroll to another view, horizontal bar does not move

Comment: Inside the animate function, what is the value of `newx`?

Comment: CGFloat(newx)  And now i got an error in this line   '        animateUnderBar(forIndex index:Int(newIndex))' . Xcode wants me to add a ';' after forIndex

Comment: I edited my answer, make sure the lines are exactly the same. Also it will animate only once the entire view has been scrolled.

Comment: Ok did it. But like i said i get an error in this line   '        animateUnderBar(forIndex index:Int(newIndex))'

Comment: Whoops! Check the new edit, it should have been `animateUnderBar(forIndex :Int(newIndex))`